# How to handle missing fields on group by query with cosmos db?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to use `Group By` with Cosmos DB dataset.

```
SELECT
    GroupedField1,
    GroupedField2,
    COUNT(1) AS GroupCount
FROM
    YourCollection
GROUP BY
    GroupedField1,
    GroupedField2;
```

but `GroupedField2` can be null or not exist on some documents. How to handle this kind of missing fields on group by query with cosmos db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CODE**

```
SELECT
c.GroupedField1,
IS_DEFINED(c.GroupedField2) ? c.GroupedField2 : null  as GroupedField2,
COUNT(1) AS GroupCount
FROM
c
GROUP  BY
c.GroupedField1,
IS_DEFINED(c.GroupedField2) ? c.GroupedField2 : null
```

This query groups the documents in the `c` container by `GroupedField1` and `GroupedField2`, and count the number of documents in each group. If `GroupedField2` is missing or `null`, it will be replaced with `null` while grouping.

Tried this code with sample input and below is the result.
**Input**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "GroupedField1": "A",
    "GroupedField2": "X"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "GroupedField1": "A",
    "GroupedField2": "Y"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "GroupedField1": "B",
    "GroupedField2": null
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "GroupedField1": "B"
}
```

**Output:**

```json
[
    {
        "GroupedField1": "B",
        "GroupedField2": null,
        "GroupCount": 2
    },
    {
        "GroupedField1": "A",
        "GroupedField2": "Y",
        "GroupCount": 1
    },
    {
        "GroupedField1": "A",
        "GroupedField2": "X",
        "GroupCount": 1
    }
]
```

[image]